# Find next Friday at 5pm from one time zone to another

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, nstimezone

I have an `NSDate` with a NZDT timezone and I need to find the next Friday at EST timezone. I have searched and have used `NSDateComponents` to generate dates but the timezone change is messing me up.

If I add 3 days to the `setWeekday` and the present day is Tuesday, then it is Thursday EST, and Friday NZDT. When EST hits 00:00:00 Tuesday, then the time is correct.  Up until 00:00:00 EST the time is a day off.

I am wondering if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: After doing a lot of research I think I should convert all times to GMT for calculations. Little more code but it looks like less headache.  I still would be curious if anybody had any idea other than converting to GMT.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect, working with GMT can simplify things.

But your question isn't clear whose "next Friday" you're trying to find.  If it's NZDT's next Friday, then the process is:

- Start with your date
- Advance to next Friday.
- Convert result to EST.

If it's EST's next Friday, then:

- Start with your date.
- Convert to EST.
- Advance to Next Friday.
- (Convert back to NZDT, if needed.)

I apologize if you're asking about something else.  Perhaps some examples would help.  Another thing that would help is if you could post your not-working code (along with some step-through values) and point out the spot where you expected a different result.